# IBM Blockchain Platform Nodejs client app can't submit transaction: No peers defined for MSP 'org1Admin' to discover from

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I have deployed a very basic IBM Blockchain network in the IBM Blockchain Platform cloud: just one peer organization and one orderer org. I have installed and instantiated a very basic contract (just CRUD operations) and I am now trying to submit the create transaction for my asset using the template Nodejs client app; here is my code:

```
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function main() {
  try {

    // Parse the connection profile. This would be the path to the file downloaded
    // from the IBM Blockchain Platform operational console.
    const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'connection.json');
    const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));

    // Configure a wallet. This wallet must already be primed with an identity that
    // the application can use to interact with the peer node.
    const walletPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);

    // Create a new gateway, and connect to the gateway peer node(s). The identity
    // specified must already exist in the specified wallet.
    const gateway = new Gateway();

    await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet: wallet, identity: 'orgAdmin' , discovery: {"enabled": true, "asLocalhost":false }});

    // Get the network channel that the smart contract is deployed to.
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('erschannel');

    // Get the smart contract from the network channel.
    const contract = network.getContract('ers_contract');

    // Submit the 'createCar' transaction to the smart contract, and wait for it
    // to be committed to the ledger.
    await contract.submitTransaction('createErsGenHash', 'ersGenHashId_1', 'ersGenHashId_1_value');
    console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

    await gateway.disconnect();

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
main();
```

I have successfully enrolled the identity **orgAdmin** and downloaded it in my local wallet (at least I got something right !!). When executing the above I get the following error:

```
C:\work\hlf>node invoke.js
2020-06-04T18:34:28.213Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: No peers defined for MSP 'orgAdmin' to discover from
Failed to submit transaction: Error: No peers defined for MSP 'orgAdmin' to discover from
```

Here is my **connection.json** profile (which I downloaded from the IBM Blockchain Platform console); it is strange that there is no orderer information:

```
{
    "name": "ORG1MSPprofile",
    "description": "Network on IBP v2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "ORG1MSP"
    },
    "organizations": {
        "ORG1MSP": {
            "mspid": "ORG1MSP",
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "184.172.233.238:31951"
            ],
            "peers": [
                "184.172.233.238:30604"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "184.172.233.238:30604": {
            "url": "grpcs://184.172.233.238:30604",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "184.172.233.238"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "184.172.233.238:31951": {
            "url": "https://184.172.233.238:31951",
            "caName": "ca",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem is in how I configured the IBM cloud blockchain network. I followed the official tutorial on building a network from [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/blockchain?topic=blockchain-ibp-console-build-network) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to your problem is this error message

```
Error: No peers defined for MSP 'orgAdmin' to discover from
```

you have registered your identity in your wallet with an mspid of `orgAdmin`. In your connection profile the defined mspid is `ORG1MSP`

```
    "organizations": {
        "ORG1MSP": {
            "mspid": "ORG1MSP"
```

so when the client tries to find a peer to use with the identity you have selected it tries to find a peer which is part of the org with mspid `orgAdmin` which is not a known mspid in your connection profile, so that results in the error message you see. The solution will be to delete and re-import your identity (or just start with a new wallet) and import the identity again with the correct mspid.

Also it's totally expected to not have the list of orderers in the connection profile. This is called a dynamic connection profile and contains the minimum information needed to interact. The rest of the required information such as other peers and orderers are `discovered` from a peer by the client sdk. As you can see in your code you have specified to enable discovery.

Comment: Thanks a lot; the problem was, as you said, when importing the identity into the wallet; previously I was importing it with: `X509WalletMixin.createIdentity("orgAdmin", enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());` now I replaced it with `X509WalletMixin.createIdentity("ORG1MSP", enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());` and it works; I guess it makes sense: an identity is given by the combination of the part (user) with the larger whole (organization).